# query builder with inner join

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I 've got a problem with the laravel query builder.
I don't understand what 's wrong.

I have 3 tables

1. **salades**
2. **ingredients**
3. **salade_ingredient** (pivot for n:n relation)

I would like to list the name of ingredients i.e. column **ingredients.nom** for salade id **22**.

sql query(work):

```
 select distinct ingredients.nom
 from ingredients, salade_ingredient,salades
 where salade_ingredient.salade_id = 22
 and ingredients.id = salade_ingredient.ingredient_id
```

laravel query (error):

```
  $Ingredients = DB::table('ingredients')
            ->select('ingredients.nom')
            ->join('salade_ingredient', 'salade_id', '=','22')
            ->join('ingredients', 'ingredients.id', '=', 'salade_ingredient.ingredient_id')
            ->join('salades','salade.id','=','salade_ingredient.salade_id')
            ->get()->distinct();
```

can you help me please? i am new with laravel.

Comment: What is the problem ? please describe.

Comment: 1) Your sql query is working fine? 2) Your laravel query give error or wrong result? 3) If give error then what was the error?

Comment: Seems, you have `select` statement before join is the problem so move that select to just before `->get()`

Comment: thanks, i have modify the ->select but i still have an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'ingredients' (SQL: select `ingredients`.`nom` from `ingredients` inner join `salade_ingredient` on `salade_id` = `$Salade["id"]` inner join `ingredients` on `ingredients`.`id` = `salade_ingredient`.`ingredient_id` inner join `salades` on `salade`.`id` = `salade_ingredient`.`salade`.`id`)
```